# Mongoose save doesn't work "id is not defined"

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

It's my first time using Mongoose and the save function is not working for me...

On user model file:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var User = mongoose.model('User', {
  name: Schema.Types.Mixed,
  gender: String,
  email: String
});

module.exports = User;
```

On my user controller file:

```
// Create a user
router.post('/', function(req, res) {
  var user = new User(req.body);
  user._id = mongoose.Types.ObjectId();
  user.save(function(err) {
    if (err) {
      return res.status(500).json({
        error: "Error creating user: " + err
      });
    }

    return res.status(200).end();
  });
});
```

I tried everything but I can't save the user object to the database: "id is not defined"
On the db the _id is a ObjectId.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

[`mongoose.model` receives collection name and a `Schema` as arguments](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/models.html), not an regular object.

So you should use the following code instead:

```
var schema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: Schema.Types.Mixed,
  gender: String,
  email: String
});
var User = mongoose.model('User', schema);
```

Comment: I have tried your solution, and I'm still receiving this error message.

Answer (score 0):

maybe we can change the code structure && remove "user._id", test please this code :

> *model file:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var UserSchema = new Schema({
  name: Schema.Types.Mixed,
  gender: String,
  email: String
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);
```

> *controller file:

```
// Create a user
router.post('/', function(req, res) {
  var user = new User(req.body);
  user.save(function(err) {
    if (err) {
      return res.status(500).json({
        error: "Error creating user: " + err
      });
    }

    return res.status(200).end();
  });
});
```

Comment: I have tried your solution, and I'm still receiving this error message.

Comment: angular.js:13642ReferenceError: id is not defined
    at Object.userService.createUser (UserService.js:71)
    at m.$scope.createUser (UserController.js:133)
    at fn (eval at compile (angular.min.js:1), <anonymous>:4:221)
    at b (angular.js:15628)
    at e (angular.js:25172)
    at m.$eval (angular.js:17378)
    at m.$apply (angular.js:17478)
    at HTMLInputElement.<anonymous> (angular.js:25177)
    at HTMLInputElement.dispatch (jquery.min.js:3)
    at HTMLInputElement.r.handle (jquery.min.js:3)(anonymous function) @ angular.js:13642